# Where can I find Hawaii public transit data?

Tags: shapefile, united-states, transportation, data

I am looking for public transportation routes and stops for Hawaii public transit.  So far I have found a shapefile for TheBus routes and stops for the island of Oahu from the state of Hawaii Office of Planning, but it did not include bus/rail files for the other islands.

Comment: You may want to look at the Open Data site: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/  There is likely potential to grab the layers from OpenStreetMap as well, but for accuracy, dealing with the transit authority over the area in question is likely the best bet...they may or may not be open to sharing their data.

Comment: GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification ) https://github.com/NotWoods/hawaii-gtfs

Answer (score 1):

You could send an email to the GIS team at Hawaii's Department of Business, Economic Development and Tourism (DBEDT):

gis@dbedt.hawaii.gov

They'll be able to answer that for you.